# Fast(er) comparison of longs in byte format?

Tags: java, performance, guava, comparator

I have a key value store that has byte[] keys.  Some of these keys will be used for longs (longs themselves, also Localdate and LocalTime instances).

I have a nice clean comparator, using standard Java and Guava:

```
    @Override
    public int compare(byte[] left, byte[] right) {
        long leftLong = Longs.fromByteArray(left);
        long rightLong = Longs.fromByteArray(right);
        return Long.compare(leftLong, rightLong);
    }
```

but it's slower than I would expect. Sorting 100,000 longs takes 100ms, whereas sorting 100,000 ints takes 6ms.

Is there a faster way to compare two longs, perhaps by avoiding the int conversion?

(You may be wondering if it really needs to be faster. If possible yes, as it will be called for every search, scan, insert, and delete of longs, dates, etc. into the store.)

Comment: pre-convert them all to longs, so you don't do multiple redundant conversions during the sort process.

Comment: you need to provide more info, how you sorting? how you benchmarking?

Comment: @SleimanJneidi  I'm using Collections.sort() on an array to benchmark.  I'm 'benchmarking' with Guava's Stopwatch.

Comment: @L.Blanc are you sure you measuring right? running the test multiple times and warming up the JVM?

Comment: Overloading `byte[]` to contain true longs as well as date/times sounds awfully dangerous.  Maybe you should explain what you're trying to accomplish instead.  This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Also, JVM microbenchmarks require a lot of preparation.  Short runs are meaningless.

Comment: @L.Blanc then it might be a good idea to show us the testing code

Comment: @MarcB.  That would be a great suggestion and I would use it if i could. The API for the key value store I'm using only takes a comparator.

Comment: @JimGarrison  As I stated above, i have a key value store that only takes byte[] keys.

Comment: Can we get past the part where everyone challenges the validity of the question instead of offering solutions. @MarcB excepted.

Comment: are you running 32 or 64 bit jvm?

Comment: Perform a radix sort instead of a regular sort with a comparator. That should be a _lot_ faster anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not surprised it takes long: allocating and destroying an order of a trillion small objects seems taxing. Why not just compare arrays themselves?

```
public int compare(byte[] left, byte[] right) {
    int cmp = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8 && cmp == 0; i++) { 
       cmp = (i == 0 || (left[i] >= 0 == right[i] >= 0)) ? left[i] - right[i] : right[i] - left[i]           
    }
    return cmp;
}
```

Comment: in original code 2 long values are created, in yours 2 ints, do you really think it will be different?

Comment: 1) ints aren't  created, they are stack variables; 2) in original code there is way more stuff created on stack inside the function calls.

Comment: 1. longs are stack variables too 2) jit can inline this, so nothing more is created. also note that Longs.fromByteArray will not use loop, but binary operations, which sometimes will be faster neither for with double comparison

Comment: In repeated runs, this is 30-40% faster.  Sorts correctly, too.

Comment: @L.Blanc Glad I could help. 
Beware of sign bit though. I updated the answer to take care of it.

Comment: Since java7 you can also use Byte.compare(byte x, byte y) to make that long line shorter: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#compare-byte-byte-

Comment: @Dima Sorry, I didn't test thoroughly enough earlier.  The original code worked better in that it sorted negative numbers before positive numbers, but it didn't always sort numerically. The second code doesn't sort negatives first, and also doesn't always sort numerically. For example, they came out: 6655056367206398535
6899858597695139415
6899670273678872055.   Hard to read, but the last one should be second.

Comment: @LaszloHirdi Using Byte.compare produces similar incorrect results. Unfortunately, with longs there is more to comparing two values than comparing the values of each of their bytes in order.  It would work for ints, tho.

Comment: @L.Blanc Sorry about that. I think, I fixed it now. 
No, comparing bytes works the same for longs and ints, that's not the problem. It's the absence of an unsigned byte type in java that complicates things here.

Comment: @Dima Thanks. Tests pass now and it's a bit faster than my variation below, so I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is another variation. It is similar to the original, but effectively does the two byte to long transformations in a single loop.  This improves performance about ~20%-30%. @Dima's version is faster.

```
    public static int compareLongs(byte[] left, byte[] right) {
        long leftLong = 0;
        long rightLong = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            leftLong <<= 8;
            rightLong <<= 8;
            leftLong |= (left[i] & 0xFF);
            rightLong|= (right[i] & 0xFF);
        }
        return Long.compare(leftLong, rightLong);
    }
```

Comment: Now, this is weird. You are doing essentially the same thing Longs.fromByteArray() does, even a little  bit more: you have 16 x (shift, or, and), and they would only have 14 ors and shifts (none needed for the lowest byte), plus you have a loop, and they don't. 
So, it seems like the only reason this version can be faster than the original is that you inline the long conversion rather than calling a function.
I wonder if it would become even faster if you replace `Long.compare` with `leftLong - rightLong`

Comment: You have to use essentially the same approach as Longs.compare, because leftLong - rightLong returns a long, and casting it to an int would cause an error if it's to big.

Comment: Yes, something like `if(leftLong == rightLong) return 0 else if (leftLong < rightLong) return -1 else return 1; ` 
I just mean to do that inline rather than calling a function, because the improvement you are getting in this version compared to the original seems to suggest that it is actually the function invocation that takes extra time, not creating the longs from bytes